# How to ensure that custom font is loaded

Tags: javascript, css, angular, fonts, webpack

I'm using Angular 2 and Webpack. Styles are added to Angular components without encapsulation.

There is a problem with custom fonts - seems like they are loaded asynchronously, so some components, whic are mesuring there size at the moment they are created, do it with initial font instead of custom.

How can I solve this problem?

As I understand, there are no any helpful events... I thought about checking currecnt font and setting some dela, but didn't find a way to chech the current font of the element. The computed value is always returned even if such font is not applied.

Or maybe some angular/webpack-specific solution can be applied?

```js
~function () {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand&_='+Date.now();
  document.head.appendChild(link);
  
  var dest = document.getElementById('dest');
  console.log(getComputedStyle(dest).fontFamily);
  var width = getComputedStyle(dest).width;
  dest.style.width = width;
}();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family: initial;">Need to handle font loading</p>
<p id="dest">Need to handle font loading</p>
<p>Need to handle font loading</p>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/589655/178988)

Comment: you could wait for `load` event on `link`

Comment: @JaromandaX, snippet is just an example. I don't know anything about styles loading events in webpack, and there is no something like that in angular comonent lifecicle. Could you help with original problem, please?

Comment: The question asks "How to ensure custom font is loaded" - I suggest waiting for the `load` event on the `link` you created to load the custom font - how is that not addressing the original problem - if the snippet isn't useful to answer the question then why include it at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Font Face Observer](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver). It will monitor when a web font is applied to the page and notify you. Currently, it's the best possible solution to determine whether your web font has been loaded.

If you really interested in the subject check out Zach Leatherman's blog. He wrote a very [comprehensive guide](https://www.zachleat.com/web/comprehensive-webfonts/) on the topic :)